# Handle file session values in php

Tags: php, session

I'm configuring payment system which callback a script on my server when payment is done.

In this script I need to unset values in the user session, I can pass trought parameter session_id(). Is any clean functions to unset values in the session with the session_id() I'll give, or should I have to make it all by hand (finding file session, fopen it, session_decode, etc ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the session_id for that user, retrieve it and then just remove the value. Not sure why you want to access the actual files directly or why the session_id would be any different for that user after payment is completed.

```
session_start();
session_id(session_id);
unset($_SESSION['removeme'];
```

Comment: Oh Great ! I did not see that session_id can be a getter ! thx dude